Where is the new bash_profile located in Big Sur OS?
Since nano ~/.bash_profile is no longer working with zsh, where is the new location for making changes to bash? Here is where it IS NOT:
~/.bash_profile,
~/.bashrc,
~/.profile,
~/.zshprofile,
~/.zshrc

Since I have already tried all of those and none of them are updating any of my bash commands, I need to know where the correct file is to edit. Yes, I've already run chsh -s /bin/bash and nothing is updating.

Hi, just a couple of things. Obviously, the command nano ~/.bash_profile actually "works". It will run perfectly and even if it doesn't you can use something else to edit the file.
I assume you mean that changes you make to ~/.bash_profile are not reflected in a shell run after you make the changes.
Could you give more information and some examples of things in the profile that are not selected in a running shell? Could you tell us how you have attempted to diagnose and fix the problem? The more you tell us the better we can help you.

Welcome to Ask Different. The [tour] explains that this isn’t a forum and how to avoid chit chat and show your research to get the best answers. When you say bash configuration is not done in bashrc or bash_profile, documenting why you feel that may avoid confusion from people that use those exact files to configure bash.

To answer the immediate question as stated in the title:
/Users/<user name>/.bash_profile

But I don't think the real question is about this ...

There seems to be a bit of confusion here. The bash_profile works with bash, not zsh. If you run the command
cat /etc/shells
You get a list of available shells in macOS. I'm running macOS 14.7.2 and get the following list (you may get some more):
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh

As you can see, bash is still available. However, macOS ships with on old version of bash. I used Homebrew to install the latest version.
Once you have the version of bash you wish to use, change the default shell to bash as follows:

Go to the Terminal app on your Mac.
Choose Terminal > Settings, then click General.
Next to “Shells open with,” select “Command (complete path),” then enter the complete path to the shell you want to use.
Restart Terminal

You can now happily use bash without concern for learning or customizing zsh.

The rest of the story may be trying to use the same dot files across different shells?

bash uses ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc depending on whether you are starting it as a login shell or not.  Read the INVOCATION section of the man page, which specifies under what conditions bash uses each file.
Of course, until you create them, they are not present.
